# Installing Turbo C++ on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, c++

I installed Vista 64 bit on my laptop. I wanted to install Turbo C++ as well. How do I install it?

It gave me a graphics error. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What version of Turbo C++?  Can you include a screenshot of the error you are getting?

Comment: AFAIK all versions of Turbo C++ are obsolete and unsupported http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 3):

Turbo C++ is [ancient](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/21751) (or antique) software, and certainly **not** supported on any 64-bit platform.

You will need to upgrade to a current version of [C++ Builder 2010](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder) or another 64-bit C++ environment to develop natively on a 64-bit OS / system.

For more details about the history of [Turbo C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) (Wikipedia).